# how to run two deep learning models for prediction sumultaniously in python using threading/multiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, prediction, yolov5

I want to use my model for detection on two videos in parallel.

i have used multithreading but innference time was very high. Than i used multiprocessing, inference was also high. I want to use my model for detection on two videos in parallel.